# How is the correct syntax to call a function in the document.ready() section?

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty sure the answer to my question is not too difficult:

I want to call a function in the `$(document).ready(function()` section of the page.
The function is already called by clicking on a button. Something like this:

```
<button  value="call function" action="#{functionClass.functionMethod}"/>
```

The function call via button works fine, how do I 'translate' it properly into 'jquery-Style'?

To be more precise:
I want to call the method when the page is loaded, not when the button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


     EinstiegsseiteController.loadTranslation();

       });
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function in the body of the anonymous `function()` of `on`, not `ready`:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.someClass', function(){
    functionClass.functionMethod();
});
```

`ready` is for events that should happen once the DOM has loaded. You don't need that event, you need the `click` event. Using it in the `on` as I've shown will work with a dynamic DOM (such as when changing `div`s with AJAX).

**Edit:** Considering the edit to the question, the function can be called on DOM load as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    functionClass.functionMethod();
});
```